How can I bring dead lines of a dot-matrix VF display back to life?
A week ago, a VF dot-matrix display, which is part of an instrument cluster, stopped displaying several lines and only left a handful of them in live state. See the area below the speedometer:

As the display was built in 1987 and is no longer available, I will have to repair it. Unfortunately, no information (schematics etc.) on the components of the module is available, but it is possible to open the backside of the cluster to access the PCB, and I do have a description of the connector (leading to the on-board computer) in my posession.
Now I'd like to know where I shall look for a fault and get the display back to life: Are crumbling soldered joints, broken capacitors, or something else the culprit? Or is this a hopeless case so that I'll have to look for a new cluster?

if part of the vacuum'd display works, I would suspect a corroded/slipped ribbon/flex cable connection.

It has no flex cables, but a connector attached to its backside.

There is very little that we can tell from this. There are certainly types of failures that will be essentially impossible for you to fix.
Instrument clusters from that era may use some chips that will be very difficult to find and if the issue is inside the VFD vacuum tube itself, a replacement glass would have to be found. The PCBs etc. will likely be fairly primitive and may be fragile.
The sudden (as opposed to a gradual or intermittent) failure without a correlation with any kind of mechanical or electrical stress points it away from PCB joints, connectors, wires and perhaps capacitors. Some clusters from that era had NiMH batteries in them which can fail and leak.
You may be able to find a specialist  in enthusiast forums who can do a swap for your existing cluster with a 'core charge' when you send them the old one (which they will then attempt to repair and sell to the next customer, or cannibalize for parts). If you dig into the thing yourself that option may vanish. There are also scrapyards  with their database of available bits and bobs.
